# Listing Homebrew installed XQuartz on OS X El Capitan

Tags: macos, homebrew

I installed XQuartz in OS X El Captain using the following command:

```
brew install Caskroom/cask/xquartz
```

After completion, `brew list` does not show XQuartz. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Isn't the program installed as XQuartz? Spotlight should find it but maybe that's not what you are trying to do? Also, `brew cask list` should list the casks you've tapped so maybe its just that?

Comment: oh! ok. `brew cask list` shows xquartz but not `brew list`!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No - you shouldn't expect to see a cask when you type `brew list` - instead use `brew cask list` to check for XQuartz and other cask-only installs.